# iText: setting PDF view defaults

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using iText for a bit of manipulating my PDFs through Java, and I'd like to make it so that a PDF default opens so that a single page fits in the window it opens, that this window is preferrably full screen, and that it has a thumbnail view on the lefthand side. I know other programs can set these view preferences, so I assume iText can, but I haven't figured out how or what part of the API I should be looking at. Do you have any suggestions?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `setViewPreferences` of the PdfWriter class.
Example:

```
writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.FitWindow 
  | PdfWriter.PageModeUseThumbs);
```

You can also selectively hide/show many element of the reader user interface, for example with the `PdfWriter.HideToolbar` flag; you can also show the document in fullscreen mode, that is very uiseful in some circumstances, with the `PdfWriter.PageModeFullScreen` flag.
Flags ara all bit masks, so you have to use the `|` operator.