# Setting the view of PDf file by 75%

Tags: java, itext

I want my PDF file that I am creating using itext-java to open 75% view. 
I mean its magnification percent should preset as 75%.
How can that be done?

Comment: Which plugin you are using for PDF generation?

Comment: I did not know a PDF could specify a 'default view size'.

Comment: @Reddy Adobe reader 9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186906/itext-setting-pdf-view-defaults?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to influence the viewer preferences,

```
writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.FitWindow);
```

however as you may see in the [jdoc](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/interfaces/PdfViewerPreferences.html) there is no option to directly set the zoom level. 
The options you have:

1. use an open parameter:

   commandline: AcroRd32.exe /A "page=8=zoom=75=OpenActions" "C:\your_document.pdf"

   url: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf#page=5&zoom=75
2. set an openAction with [javascript](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf):

   `PdfAction action = PdfAction.javaScript("", writer);`
   `writer.setOpenAction(action);`

Please note with the 2nd option that for e.g PDF/A files javascript is forbidden and/or may be disabled/unsupported for certain viewers.